# Not receiving correct data from firebird database when using PHP

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, firebird

I have some very odd situation. I am making a query to a firebird database and there is mismatch with the result in PHP. In DB the result is just fine, but when it comes to PHP there are different values.

The query:

```
 SELECT LIST(t."ID", ',') ID,t."Date", LIST(n."Name",',') Name
    FROM "Tests" t
    LEFT JOIN "Names of tests" n ON t."Name ID" = n."ID"
    WHERE t."Locked" = 0
    GROUP BY t."Date"
    ORDER BY t."Date" DESC
```

**Result in DB:**

ID = 546,552  Date = 23.10.2015  Name = Математика (тест),География(тест)

**Result in PHP:**

> ```
>   ID   => 0x0000000200000000,
>     Date => 2015-10-23,
>     Name => 0x0000000500000000
> ```

I am using "UTF-8" encoding when connecting to DB with ibase_connect() the database encoding is WIN1251.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result type of [`LIST()`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-aggfuncs-list) is a blob, not a `CHAR` or `VARCHAR`. I don't use PHP myself, but I believe that the Firebird/Interbase driver for PHP requires you to explicitly request the blob.

The values you see for `ID` and `Name` are the blob ids that can be used to request the blobs.

You have two options:

1. Request the blob value using these blob ids, see [`ibase_blob_open`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-blob-open.php) and [`ibase_blob_get`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-blob-get.php) (afaik, you will need to do the correct byte to character conversion yourself)
2. Cast the value to a `VARCHAR` (eg `CAST(LIST(t."ID", ',') AS VARCHAR(2048)) AS ID`)

The downside of the second option is that if you can have really long results, then you also need to cast to a long `VARCHAR`, otherwise you get truncation errors; and unfortunately varchars are restricted to 32K-2 bytes (8191 characters for UTF8), and a row as a whole to 64K bytes.